# Why background-color is not working for me?

Tags: html, css

I'm creating a dating site to learn web dev and I don't know how to make background-color work, it just doesn't on specific divs. What should I change? I tried a lot of things but nothing happened.

Adding lorem ipsum so I can ask this question... just skip this

> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi ut felis magna. Cras lectus sapien, porttitor quis elit id, lacinia pellentesque urna. Fusce gravida felis sit amet purus mattis, sed faucibus turpis hendrerit. Integer convallis sagittis pulvinar. Curabitur tristique faucibus lorem iaculis egestas. Vivamus vitae lacus placerat, efficitur diam et, volutpat augue. Cras at purus vitae neque ultricies iaculis. Maecenas pellentesque ipsum nisi.

**My code:**

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  color: black;
}

body {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.container {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-top: 10px;
  width: 95%;
  height: 750px;
}

nav {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  font-family: 'Pattaya', sans-serif;
  font-size: 39px;
}

.logo {
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-top: auto;
  margin-bottom: auto;
}

.menu {
  margin-top: auto;
  margin-bottom: auto;
}

nav ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}

nav ul li {
  padding: 30px;
  display: inline-block;
}

nav ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

nav ul li a:hover {
  background-color: #ede;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.circle {
  z-index: -2;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #ede;
  clip-path: circle(600px at right 800px);
}

.circlebig {
  z-index: -2;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #ede;
  clip-path: circle(940px at left);
}

.content {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  font-family: 'Rubik', sans-serif;
  font-size: 56px;
}

.text {
  transform: translateY(25%);
}

.love {
  font-size: 70px;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, red, orange, yellow, green, blue, indigo, violet);
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
  animation: move 400s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes move {
  to {
    background-position: 4500vh;
    
}

.freeplan {
  z-index: 3;
  display: block;
  background-color: #666 !important;
}

.paidplan {
  z-index: 3;
  display: block;
  background-color: #35f !important;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Pattaya&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Rubik:ital,wght@1,300&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
<main>
  <div class="container">
    <nav>
      <div class="logo">
        <a href="index.html"><img src="img/logo.png"></a>
      </div>
      <div class="menu">
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#"> &#8291 &#8291 Plans &#8291 &#8291 </a></li>
          <li><a href="#"> &#8291 &#8291 About &#8291 &#8291 </a></li>
          <li><a href="#"> &#8291 &#8291  Login &#8291 &#8291 </a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>
    <section class="content">
      <div class="freeplan">
        Freeplan
        <img src="img/kiss.png">
      </div>
      <div class="paidplan">
        Paidplan
        <img src="img/kiss.png">
      </div>
      <img src="img/kiss.png">
    </section>
    <div class="circle"></div>
    <div class="circlebig"></div>
  </div>
</main>
```

Comment: Please be more specific on what your problem is. Like what div's are not getting colour for example.

Answer (score 3):

You didn't close the curly brackets:

```css
  @keyframes move {
    to {
        background-position: 4500vh;
    } // <==
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you may miss the '@keyframes' curly bracket. please replace the @keyframes' as like my code.

```
@keyframes move {
    to {
        background-position: 4500vh;
    }
}
```